# The HTML I wrote is different from the HTML rendered by browsers in wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I was working on a project (wordpress theme) and There was no problem until recently when I changed my PC (and changed to windows 10) ..

I saw that in Chrome's developer tools there's HTML from that of what I've already written .. however when I viewed the page's source it's the same as the original HTML so I suspect it has something to do with wordpress's javascript

Example: FOCUS ON THE `<header>` ELEMENT

```
<?php?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>> 
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'quietnoise' ); ?></a>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div id="topbar" class="clear">
    <nav id="header-important-link-left" class="important-links-left">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'important-links-left', 'menu_id' => 'important-links-menu-left' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
      <?php if (get_theme_mod('is_in_header')){ ?><div class="social-media-box" id="header-social-media-box">
     <?php $links_list = array('facebook'=>'facebook','twitter'=>'twitter','google_plus'=>'google-plus',
        'youtube'=>'youtube','linkedin'=>'linkedin','instagram'=>'instagram','codepen'=>'codepen','pinterest'=>'pinterest-p','tumblr'=>'tumblr');  foreach ($links_list as $slug => $fa_slug) {
        if(get_theme_mod($slug.'_link')){
            ?><a href ='<?php echo get_theme_mod($slug.'_link');?>'><span class="fa fa-<?php echo $fa_slug; ?>"></span></a><?php } } } ?> </div><nav id="header-important-links-right" class="important-links-right">
    <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'important-links-right', 'menu_id' => 'important-links-menu-right' ) ); ?>
    </nav>
    </div>
        <div class="site-branding">
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <?php
            $description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
            if ( $description || is_customize_preview() ) : ?>
                <p class="site-description"><?php echo $description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
            <?php
            endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="main-navigation" class="site-navigation" role="navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'quietnoise' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_id' => 'primary-menu' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #main-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

the code rendered by Chrome

```
<body class="single single-post postid-1 single-format-standard">
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content">Skip to content</a>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
    <div id="topbar" class="clear">
    <nav id="header-important-link-left" class="important-links-left">
    <div id="important-links-menu-left" class="menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li></ul></div>
    </nav>
       </div><nav id="header-important-links-right" class="important-links-right">
    <div id="important-links-menu-right" class="menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li></ul></div>
    </nav>
    </header></div>
        <div class="site-branding">
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/" rel="home">QuietNoise</a></h1>
                            <p class="site-description">Just another WordPress site</p>
                    </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="main-navigation" class="site-navigation" role="navigation">
        <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false">Primary Menu</button>
            <div id="primary-menu" class="menu"><ul><li class="page_item page-item-2"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li></ul></div>
        </nav><!-- #main-navigation -->
    <!-- #masthead -->
```

the  element closetag's place is different from the original code

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href ='<?php echo get_theme_mod($slug."_link");?>'>
```

instead of this

```
<a href ='<?php echo get_theme_mod($slug.'_link');?>'>
```

in #header-social-media-box. I think there's a mismatch in understanding single and double quotation marks.

If you use a text editor (e.g. Brackets or something else) and correct indentation, this type of problem immediately stands out (Brackets (with my color settings) showed this part in red - so I saw there's a problem).

With this problem the other half of **header** is not there (not even the header closing tag), so the browser closes the tag where it should close.